# Use swift global variable (singleton) from Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, swift

I'm using a global swift variable to create a Singleton like instance. Due to global variables being dispatch_once by default in Swift it works pretty well.

```
/// LPGlobal.swift
import Foundation
let mySingleton : LPSingleton = LPSingleton()

/// LPSingleton.swift
import Foundation
class LPSingleton {
    let myConstant = 10.0
}
```

Reference from Swift:

```
/// LPAnySwiftClass.swift
import Foundation
class LPSwiftClass {    
    init () {
        println("my singleton constant: \(mySingleton.myConstant)")
    }
}
```

The Question is: how can I access this LPSingleton class from within Interface Builder?. There is no "Swift class" in the Object library. Do I need to create an Objective-C singleton in order to "act" as a bridge?.

Note: The LPSingleton class is not a subclass of NSObject !!!

Thanks
Luis

Comment: IB only works with ObjC objects.  To make a Swift class available to IB, simply inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: Thanks Darren that's what I suspected, thank you for your confirmation. Maybe in the future is implemented, we'll see...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: As discussed in the comments, this works only if you subclass NSObject. At the time of this answer there isn't a way to access "pure" Swift classes through IB.

You can drag an "Object" item into IB and assign it a Swift class.

Pick "Object" from the IB palette:

[image: object]

Drag it under your view controller on the left sidebar:

[image: object under vc]

And assign it to your class in the object inspector on the right:

[image: object inspector]

Comment: Thanks richard, however, after doing so I get this warning:  *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x608000032c60 of class '_TtC6Prueba11LPSingleton' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
(lldb). The application crash and stops on "libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`-[SwiftObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]:"

Comment: If I add ": NSObject" to my LPSingleton class then the warning disappears and application runs, but my question is: how can I do this with a top level swift class (not a subclass). I've edited the original question to notice that I don't want a subclass.

Comment: Ah. That makes it harder. I wouldn't mind being proven wrong but I think that requirement might make the answer "you can't." Any practical reason you don't want to subclass from NSObject or is this more of "I wonder if" question?

Comment: Thank you Richrad, "Any practical reason you don't want to subclass from NSObject?": I think the right answer would be "I wanted to do it with Swift only which I though could be possible, then discovered it wasn't" :). Do you mind editing your answer to reflect the need to subclass from NSObject because IB only works with ObjC objects?. Then I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks again.

Comment: I see! It'll be interesting to see where Apple takes this going forward (i.e. when the first Swift-only frameworks start appearing) I've edited my answer.